# resolv.conf - read-only filesystem

Tags: debian, raspbian, readonly, resolv.conf

I'm in the process of configuring raspbian jessie to run as read-only.
Only `/tmp` is writable and the system is configured to write DHCP ip information in `/tmp`.

Everything is working fine except `/etc/resolv.conf`. It just doesn't get updated during boot.

I have tried using a symbolic link.

`rm /etc/resolv.conf
touch /tmp/resolv.conf
ln -s /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

But because `/tmp` is emptied on reboot, `/tmp/resolve.conf` can't be updated because it doesn't exist.

So I tried creating the file during boot.

`touch /tmp/resolv.conf` in `/etc/rc.local`

The file gets created, but only after dhclient runs, because there are no DNS entries in it. If I run dhclient after the system has booted it writes the DNS servers to the file successfully.

How can I make `resolv.conf` work on a read-only file system?

Comment: How do you make the system as read-only? By the way, there are other things that might want to write to disk, the logging system being one of them.

Comment: I made the system read-only by editing /etc/fstab. I took care of any programs that want to write to the disk. Currently my problem is resolv.conf.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This did it

`rm /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sed -i 's/\/etc\/resolv.conf/\/tmp\/resolv.conf/g' /sbin/dhclient-script`

Comment: You are changing files behind the back of the package manager. That's not recommended and can lead to surprises even in read-only systems.

Comment: I agree with @FerencWágner - this is specifically what the hooks are there to avoid.

Comment: Of course I would prefer doing it the proper way. But I don't have that much experience with Linux and I can't re-discover the wheel. Any chance there's a guide somewhere on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

From the dhclient-script man pages,

> **Hooks**
>
> When it starts, the client script first defines a shell
> function, make_resolv_conf , which is later used to create the
> /etc/resolv.conf file. To override the default behaviour, redefine
> this function in the enter hook script.
>
> On after defining the make_resolv_conf function, the client script
> checks for the presence of an executable
> /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks script, and if present, it invokes the
> script inline, using the Bourne shell '.' command. The entire
> environment documented under OPERATION is available to this script,
> which may modify the environment if needed to change the behaviour of
> the script. If an error occurs during the execution of the script, it
> can set the exit_status variable to a nonzero value, and
> /sbin/dhclient-script will exit with that error code immediately after
> the client script exits.

So you should be able to edit `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks` and add entries in there to create `/tmp/resolv.conf` with the correct permissions if it doesn't exist, removing and re-creating the symlink if necessary.

Checking on Debian, there appears to be a `dhclient-enter-hooks.d` directory with script pieces in it, so you might be able to just add something there, depending on your distribution / version of dhclient (Raspbian in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot#resolv.conf. It recommends using the [resolvconf](https://packages.debian.org/resolvconf) package. As you've already fiddled with your software, it may require some undoing to get it work properly, but it's a well thought out solution to this problem and more.